# Generate a Generator Matrix from a ldpc parity check matrix

Tags: matrix, generator, channel, parity

I have generated a LDPC `parity check matrix` using Gallager approach for `n = 20` , `j = 3` and `k = 4`.

The parity check matrix is defined by:
[image]

The problem is, I don't know how to proceed further to generate the `codeword` for which I'll need the `generator matrix`. The Gauss elimination method was of no help. Can u suggest a better method to find the `generator matrix`.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

We want to use Gaussian elimination to normalize this parity check matrix H into normalized form [P I].

Since H is a 15x20 matrix, P would be a 15x5 matrix and I would be a 15x15 matrix.

However, observe that the last 15 entries of the first row in H are all zeroes.

Thus, it is impossible to normalize H using Gaussian elimination alone.

We might try to use a slightly different approach to normalize H, namely the method suggested in this StackExchange answer https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2818445/how-do-i-find-parity-check-matrix-if-generator-matrix-cant-be-written-in-standa :

1. Convert H to row-echolon form
2. Perform column-swaps to produce normalized from [P I]
3. Create the normalized generator matrix G = [I PT]
4. Undo the column-swaps from step 2 onto the generator matrix G

However, for the matrix H given in your example, this approach does also not work because the rows are linearly dependent and the row-echolon form has all-zeroes as its last two rows.

The issue of how to generate a reasonable generator matrix G even when the parity check matrix H has linear dependencies is discussed here:

- [https://www.cs.utoronto.ca/~radford/ftp/LDPC-2000-03-19/dep-H.html](https://www.cs.utoronto.ca/%7Eradford/ftp/LDPC-2000-03-19/dep-H.html)  That page also discusses other pathological cases (e.g. rows in H that only contain a single 1)
- [http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~radford/ftp/LDPC-2012-02-11/encoding.html](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Eradford/ftp/LDPC-2012-02-11/encoding.html)